# error while loading shared libraries: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block

Tags: node.js

I am trying to install nodejs on my centos machine and getting the following error can anyone advise.

```
[root@ip-10-1-202-188 /]# npm install nodejs node: error while loading shared libraries: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a glibc-related issue. Assuming you installed from one of the NodeSource repositories, [here](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/513) is the related existing issue.

If you compile from source or use one of the pre-compiled binaries from nodejs.org or use nvm, this should not be a problem.